# Pluralization in vue i18n

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n, plural

Hi i am trying to pluralize based on https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/pluralization.html

```
imageCount== 1
          ? $t("message.imageMessage", 1, { imageCount})
          : $t("message.imageMessage", imageCount, {
              imageCount
            })



imageMessage: '{imageCount} image downloaded | {imageCount} images downloaded'
```

Problem : currently it is displaying bo the messages which should not happen,is there anything wrong in the way which i have implemented?

[image]

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-haze-z9jzt?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: From the documentation you linked ~ _"Your template will need to use **`$tc()`** instead of `$t()`"_. Demo ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-neumann-e2gdn?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: ohh just missed this point,thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/pluralization.html)...

> Your template will need to use **`$tc()`** instead of `$t()`.

---

You can also improve / shorten your code somewhat by using `{n}` or `{count}` in your translation strings...

```js
en: {
  message: {
    imageMessage: "{n} image downloaded | {n} images downloaded"
  }
}
```

and in your templates

```js
$tc("message.imageMessage", imageCount)
```

Answer (score 3):

With `vue@3` and `vue-i18n@9` and Composition API, with locale key being:

```json
{
  message: {
    imageMessage: "no images | 1 image downloaded | {n} images downloaded"
  }
}
```

It's enough to do:

```js
$t('message.imageMessage', { n: images.length })
// OR 
$t('message.imageMessage', images.length)
```